# Network drive only reconnects from File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, network-shares

I'm facing a weird issue with my network drive mapping after rebooting my machine.

This is Windows 10 Enterprise, fully updated.

Whenever I start up my laptop, it can no longer connect to the network drive; even though I've set it up as a persistent network drive mapping.

I open Visual Studio, and try to open the recent solution that points to **P:\Folder1\Folder2\MySolution.sln**. Visual Studio tells me that it **cannot** connect to the location.
When I log in, I also get a notification that Windows cannot connect to all network drives. I only have one set up, so I'm sure it's talking about the P drive.

However, I have a shortcut to Folder2 in my Quick Access in File Explorer. When I click that link, it **can** access the path (which is set to the P-drive, not the full network location. I've double checked that).

After having opened Folder2 in File Explorer, Visual Studio **can** now open the solution from the same link.

This isn't just happening for Visual Studio. I've seen it happen for Notepad++, Office (Excel and Word), and applications I've written myself.

Why is the network drive unmapped until I try to open it via Quick Access?

Note that when I use the full network path (without the drive mapping), it **always** works, so the problem seems to be related to the network drive mapping itself.
I'm also connecting to the drive using my own credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with a network drive. I added a batch file to startup to nudge the network drive into connecting.  The code is below.

```
TIMEOUT /t 15
net use z: \\xxx.xxx.x.xxx\
```

I added the timeout to allow windows and the network services to start.  You can change that based on how quick/slow your PC is.  I mapped it to z, but change that to whatever you have

Comment: Just to make sure, that would make it `net use p: \\myserver\mysharedfolder` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct